# Magento 2: Theme change field is missing in Design Tab

Tags: theme, design, magento2.1.5

I created a new theme but when i tried to change the theme from

`stores -> configuration -> design` Tab  I found that theme change field is missing from design tab. Please look at screen-shot below. Can anyone tell me why theme change field is not coming. I am using  Magento ver. 2.1.5.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Magento 2.1.x they have moved themes into content=>design
[image]

Comment: Correct answer, though an odd decision. A theme is not normally considered a part of the content.

Answer (score 1):

First check that your theme structure looks like this under,

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/
├── <theme>/
│   ├── etc/
│   │   ├── view.xml
│   ├── web/
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   ├── logo.svg
│   ├── registration.php
│   ├── theme.xml
│   ├── composer.json
```

Check all the files properly.
And delete `var/generation` files and then refresh any admin page having added the theme files to the files system, your theme gets registered and added to the database
And also delete any entry made in database of your theme ,if any.
Or you can send your code so i can check whats's wrong.
Hope this helps you..

Comment: I delete my theme and cleared cache, but still theme fields are missing. It is missing in default Magento 2.1.5 version. Can you tell me how to add this.

Comment: Make sure you have deleted the theme from database also.And then try to find the theme under :- Content > Theme. Not under configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands to enable the developer mode, to disable the cache and etc:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"
mage deploy:mode:set developer
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage cache:disable &&
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy && 
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```